# Whats the best way to implement a Database into a C#-Programm?

Tags: c#, mysql, database

What is the best way to use a Database in an Open-Source Program which I want to publish on GitHub?
I've had a problem with publishing my programs on GitHub because you were able to see the Connection String. That allowed you to edit the Database how you wanted to. Is there a way to encrypt the ConnectionString when I upload it to GitHub? Is there another way to solve this problem?

Comment: You want to write an Open-Source program but you want to hide the _connectionstring_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encryption is only as reliable as the way you store the key, wich would have to be as public as anything else used in the code. The requirements of Secrecy and publishing on GitHub are inherently at odds.

One way would be to store stuff like the connecting string in a configuration file that you do not share on github. Or use a local Network only Database with default User values, wich do not help any attacker on your Production Systems.

If for some odd reason access to the same shared datasource is required across all compilations/installations, you could hide the Database behind a WebService whose code you do not share. As the programm only needs to worry about accessing a WebService, you would not need any DB values.  Or even wich DB is used in the backend.